# Youtube v3 api fetch all video from user's playlist android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Is there any example in Android for retrieving **all video play-list** of particular user or you can say channel, Because I have tried so much and also reads docs

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java

but did not getting accurate example for Android,

Any body have done then please suggest me

Thanks